# problem with get html tags from html entities

Tags: php, html-entities

My string is like below,

```
$string = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Property Name :&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;span class=&quot;getvariable&quot; id=&quot;get_variable-89&quot; name=&quot;get_variable&quot;&gt;[[seeking_property_name]]&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";
```

I have tried to decode it as below,

```
echo html_entity_decode($string);
```

and as,

```
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT);
```

and as,

```
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

But it is not working.

The result should be,

```
<p><strong>Property Name :</strong> <span class="getvariable" id="get_variable-89" name="get_variable">[[seeking_property_name]]</span></p>
```

can you tell me what is issue here?

---

**I found a solution:**

```
htmlspecialchars_decode(html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES))
```

it is working for me!

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. What output do you expect?

Comment: To add on to @JayBlanchard's response, what output is it currently giving you?

Comment: thanks for reply, I have update my question for that.

Comment: Why doesn't your first solution work?

Comment: All three approaches in your question work fine for the string you've posted: https://3v4l.org/dRXMZ

Comment: Even htmlspecialchars_decode works for the string you posted. Can you please show us what it's currently outputting or any error it may be showing?

Comment: I have also checked it, but from my code level it shows me string without any change

Comment: htmlspecialchars_decode  also not working for me :(

Comment: Can you post the actual code you're running? Your question refers to two different variables (`$string` and `$data`) so presumably there's more going on somewhere.

Comment: I got my solution, I have updated it in my question , and thank you for your help